# Trying to Use Custom URL ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Trying to using Custom route URL in MVC, but not working

I need URL like `Admin/Company` etc, but there is also Admin Controller that is conflicting with Company Controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Company",
            url: "Admin/Company",
            defaults: new {controller = "Company", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Trying to do this, but don't know why Admin Controller calls first, I need Admin in the URL. Any help?

Comment: It seems you are making life difficult for yourself. If there's an `AdminController`, then "/Admin" will go there. If you cannot add company management there, you have to make a complex workaround like you suggest.... Why don't you rethink this and use "/Company/Admin"?

Comment: @Sohaib Azhar: If you have `Admin` controller and `Company` controller then describe all requirements to your routes and also include all related code. Better show all related parts of the `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`.

Comment: @JHBonarius I did think of the /Company/Admin, but I need the Admin part before

Comment: @Jackdaw can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Sohaib Azhar: Actually, you are defined correct route. If you enter in the browser `Admin/Company` URL you will activate `CompanyController.Index()` action method.  And If you will enter `/Admin` or `/Admin/Index` URL you will enter to `AdminController.Index()` action method. So, what is your problem? You should describe you problem more **precisely** and show all related code parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update it to say `controller = "Admin"`

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Company",
            url: "Admin/Company",
            defaults: new {controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }
        );
```

See my comments. They might help.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Company",  //route name
                url: "Admin/Company",  // url pattern
                defaults: new {controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }  //defaults for route
            );
```

Then in your Admin controller you can add your Company View:

```
public ActionResult Company()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Company Page";

            return View();
        }
```